# How do I know if Amazon successfully sent the email

Tags: python, django, email, amazon-ses

In my django project, I am sending emails using Amazon-ses and some of the emails I have to send are critical. In this case I want to make sure that my email has been sent successfully, so that if not sent, I can resend it. Is there any way for me to know if the email was sent successfully?

Comment: Depending on what "critical" means in your context, you should consider that email might not be a safe transport for your project. There are many edge cases in delivery and multiple partners involved that you might not have control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon SES forwards bounce and complaint notifications to you by email or sends them to an Amazon SNS topic, depending on how you set up your Amazon SES account.

This link includes a detailed explanation of how to set up one: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/handling-bounces-and-complaints/

Delivery notifications, which are triggered when Amazon SES successfully delivers one of your emails to a recipient’s mail server, are sent to you only through Amazon SNS. Having said that, Amazon will charge you for using Amazon SNS to receive bounce, complaint, and delivery notifications.

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html